# How to execute an sql file after a container of mysql image is built for the first time

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an `data.sql` file in the same folder as `Dockerfile` & `docker-compose.yml` file.
I want when the **first time** the container is being built with mysql image the commands written in the `data.sql` file of mine should execute.

In the `data.sql` I have:

```
create database db1;
create database db2;
create database db3;
create database db4;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on db1.* to 'NORMAL_USER'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on db2.* to 'NORMAL_USER'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on db3.* to 'NORMAL_USER'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on db4.* to 'NORMAL_USER'@'%';
```

In the `Dockerfile` i have written:

```
ADD data.sql data.sql
```

In the `docker-compose.yml` file I have written:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ROOT_USER_PASS
      MYSQL_USER: NORMAL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: NORMAL_USER_PASS
    ports:
      - "5000:3306"
    networks:
      - internal_net
    volumes:
      - mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  internal_net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql:
```

Comment: I recommend to write the `.sql`-script idempotent (e.g. use `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ...`) and then mount said `.sql`-script in the container to `/docker-entrypoint-initdtb.d` as described on the [mysql `dockerhub.com` page under "Initializing a fresh instance"](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

Comment: @Turing85 I understood the first part and I will do it, can you give the code for 2nd part to mount the sql file to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d this is where I'm really struggling and I don't know how to do it

Comment: The [relevant documentation (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) has examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we start adding this feature, we need the current error in the `docker-compose.yml`: the volume `mysql` needs a mount location. I suspect that it should be mounted as data-directory to `/var/lib/mysql`. Please correct the path if it should be mounted somewhere else:

```
...
services:
  mysql:
    ...
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ...
```

---

The [`hub.docker.com` page of the MySQL container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) states under **Initializing a fresh instance** that:

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions `.sh`, `.sql` and `.sql.gz` that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. ...

The script is only executed when no data is found in the data directory (`/var/lib/mysql` by default). Thus, we can simply [mount `data.sql` to this directory through a `volume` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes):

```
...
services:
  mysql:
    ...
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql:ro
    ...
```